# Почему происходит ошибка <bound method Restaurant.open_restaurant of <__main__.Restaurant object at 0x0000023C7FB8E9A0>> при выводе?

Tags: python, python-3.x

При выводе моего кода происходит данная ошибка, можете подсказать почему?
<bound method Restaurant.open_restaurant of <**main**.Restaurant object at 0x0000023C7FB8E9A0>>

```
class Restaurant():

def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):

    self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
    self.cuisine_name = cuisine_type

def describe_restaurant(self):
    print(self.restaurant_name)
    print(self.cuisine_name)
    print(self.open_restaurant)

def open_restaurant(self):
    print("Наш ресторан открывается!")


class Restaurant():
    restaurant_0 = Restaurant('У Ашота', 'Шаурмечная')
    restaurant_1 = Restaurant('Сицилия', 'Ресторан корейской кухни')
    restaurant_2 = Restaurant('Барнаул', 'Ресторан')
    restaurant_0.describe_restaurant()
    restaurant_1.describe_restaurant()
    restaurant_2.describe_restaurant()
```

Comment: Пишу код в Visual Studio Code

Comment: синтаксис - точно `()` не нужны?

Comment: @Сергей а куда их писать?

Comment: Сложный вопрос. Ошибка относится к строке `open_restaurant` И вот куда можно тут вставить `()`? Попробуйте три варианта: 1) до `open`, 2) между `open` и `restaurant`, 3) после `restaurant`. :-) Попробуйте также учебник посмотреть про вызов методов класса.

Comment: @Сергей Спасибо! Увидел что я пытался напечатать метод класса :))) просто стёр print() и всё)

Answer (score 1):

Я пока вижу, что когда вы вызываете метод `describe_restaurant()`, вы пытаетесь распечатать значение, которое является методом, а не полем вашего класса: `print(self.open_restaurant)`. Замените эту строку на `self.open_restaurant()`

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!